# Is iTunes able to play H.265?

Tags: itunes

I can't find out any info about if iTunes is able to play [H.265/High Efficiency Video Coding (HEVC)](http://x265.org) format.

Do you know if this is posible?

Yosemite 10.10, iTunes version 12.1.

Comment: Which iTunes? Which OS? - in 6 months or 2 years, this might become confusing without specifics...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, according to Apple on [this list](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201290). It does not contain H.265.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't wanted to try before ensure that works.

Answer (score 5):

Apple supports H.265, but so far only in FaceTime on iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 Plus. From iTunes menu, H.265 video files can not be read since iTunes have no ability of playing HEVC/H.265 format. Sometimes, even you can add H.265 to iTunes, you still cannot sync them to Apple devices. That is to say, users can't stream or even play H.265 video outside of the FaceTime environment.

Answer (score 1):

As usual in OS X if you load third party apps with the codecs they most likely will become available to other applications. I can't give specific details in this case. Certainly BlackMagic Design products are starting to encode in H.265 so loading one of their helper applications may well get you the codecs onto OS X for iTunes or VLC or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

iVI Pro can convert from 265 into iTunes.

I assume their non-Pro version can too, but that's what I'm using.